# git push says everything up to date when it definitely is not

Tags: git, push

I have a public repository. No one else has forked, pulled, or done anything else to it. I made some minor changes to one file, successfully committed them, and tried to push. It says 'Everything up-to-date'. There are no branches. I'm very, very new to git and I don't understand what on earth is going on.

`git remote show origin` tells me:

```
HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

Any ideas what I can do to make this understand that it's NOT up to date?

Thanks

Updates:
`git status`:

```
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       histmarkup.el
#       vendor/yasnippet-0.6.1c/snippets/
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

`git branch -a`:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/master
```

`git fsck`:

```
dangling tree 105cb101ca1a4d2cbe1b5c73eb4a238e22cb4998
dangling tree 85bd0461f0fcb1618d46c8a80d3a4a7932de34bb
```

Update 2: I re-opened the modified file, and the modifications I KNOW I had made were gone. So I added them again, went through the rigamarole of `git status`, `git add filename`, `git commit -m "(message)"`, and `git push origin master`, and all of a sudden it works the way it's supposed to.

Update 3: `git reflog` output:

```
009251 HEAD@{0}: commit: added copy/paste keybindings
06920f9 HEAD@{1}: commit: Minor .gitignore tweak
84aa30c HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from master to master
84aa30c HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from ec16cca979045547a5444e20f48ed468dee81dd4 to master
ec16cca HEAD@{4}: commit: Added keybindings for copy/paste
5c4a611 HEAD@{5}: commit: remember-mode keybinding to M-R
f3e4729 HEAD@{6}: commit: Correcting last push which wiped out some stuff
fa28a3e HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from master to fa28a3ed80eb0c6d4375ae77060d5cb4143d6a8e^0
84aa30c HEAD@{8}: commit: Modified keybindings, added LaTeX hook
10e7718 HEAD@{9}: commit: Added a few keybindings
d62378b HEAD@{10}: commit (initial): first commit
```

Comment: How did you push? What was the output of the push command? What does `git log --decorate` show you?

Comment: I pushed with `git push origin master`. The output was "Everything up-to-date". `git log --decorate` shows me 3 commits including yesterday's, but not today's.

Comment: Have you tried to pull from the other side? Does that work?

Comment: I haven't, because I don't know how to do that or what it is/does. GitHub help's description of it assumes having forked the project, which I haven't.

Comment: What are you pushing to?  (I haven't used git hub - I push over an intranet?)  My git remote show origin has Fetch URL: tom@mypc:/my/dir/.git
Push  URL: tom@mypc:/my/dir/.git before the HEAD branch: master

Comment: Fetch URL: git@github.com:username/repo.git Push URL: git@github.com:username/repo.git (default values recommended in github's setup instructions)

Comment: What about `git log --all --decorate`? If you can't see today's commits it sounds like they're not on your master branch.

Comment: Yes, that command shows 3 commits up to and including yesterday's, but not today's.

Comment: where are you doing the push?  On your home pc or on the git hub?

Comment: Where (and how) did you make today's commits?

Comment: @Tom No, I haven't cloned it. I don't think so, anyway. But I'm not doing anything differently from those previous 3 commits, nor from multiple successful commits/pushes on another project. Everything I'm doing this time worked the last 3 times.

Comment: @Tom Doing the push on the home pc. As always. @Charles I've explained in previous comments how I did the commits.

Comment: @Wolf: I also wanted to know where, because if `git log --all --decorate` only shows you three commits then the other commits aren't on any branch in your local repository.

Comment: @Charles: What do you mean by 'where'? I'm on my home pc. pwd is the root directory of the project, as always.

Comment: Is your home PC where you made "today's commits"? And they're not visible with `git log` in the repository where you made them?

Comment: @Charles: Yes to both questions.

Comment: OK, well that's the more serious issue. If you've made a whole lot of commits and the are no longer in your current repository then something has gone wrong before push. The fact that when you push master to origin it no longer surprising that you are "up to date", the commits aren't on the local side of the push either.

Comment: Can you update your question with the _complete_ output of `git status`, `git branch -a` and `git fsck`?

Comment: @Wolf: I can't see anything wrong there. Next step, what does `git reflog` output?

Comment: @Charles: I just added another update to the question. Short version: For no apparent reason, it works now. Not a single, solitary clue why or how.

Comment: @Wolf: OK, what but what does `git reflog` show?

Comment: Voting to close. Without the `reflog` output it's impossible to tell what might have happened last time around so I don't see how this question is answerable.

Comment: @Charles: Sorry, I had other, non-computer-related stuff I had to do. `git reflog` output added to original post.

Comment: If you do `git branch alt ec16cca` and then `git log alt` are they "today's commits" ?

Comment: @Charles: Yes, it's a complete list, looks like.

Comment: OK, it look like you detached your `HEAD`. You didn't do something like `git checkout origin/master` did you?

Comment: I have `git checkout master` in my history, but it can only have been as part of trying to fix the issue of push not updating. I did google the problem and try out a few things I found that way before I came here.

Comment: @Wolf @Charles Is this problem solved now?  I have been following it and the cause of problem/solution is new to me.  Can it be summerised?

Comment: @Tom It does seem to have been solved, somehow; I still don't know what I originally did to cause the problem nor how it got fixed. I am wondering, though, whether having "detached my HEAD" is going to cause future problems and whether there's something I should do at this stage to fix that detachment.

Comment: @Tom I can only accept/vote on answers, not comments, but if Charles writes an answer I'll do that. Thanks for your help too.

Comment: @Wolf: I'm trying to work out this entry: `fa28a3e HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from master to fa28a3ed80eb0c6d4375ae77060d5cb4143d6a8e^0` I presume that you didn't manually do `git checkout fa28a3ed80eb0c6d4375ae77060d5cb4143d6a8e^0` but I'm struggling to work out what command might have caused this. A rebase, perhaps?

Comment: @Charles: No, I didn't run anything like that. The only `git checkout`s I have in my history are two instances of `git checkout master`.

Comment: @Wolf: I'm stumped, then. Something did a checkout that detached your `HEAD` from the master branch. I would expect that to be another `git` command but I can't think of anything that you are likely to have done.

Comment: @Charles: Weird. Do I need to reattach HEAD to anything, then, or is it okay as it is?

Comment: @Wolf: Well, when you did a `git checkout master` you moved your `HEAD` back onto the master branch so there's nothing you need to do now, but the consequence was that the commits that you had made when you were on the detached HEAD were orphaned. By creating the `alt` branch, they're now all visible again but it's still a mystery to me what you did to detach your `HEAD` in the first place.

Answer (score 14):

Try

```
git config push.default tracking
```

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config :

push.default

Defines the action git push should take if no refspec is given on the command line, no refspec is configured in the remote, and no refspec is implied by any of the options given on the command line. Possible values are:

```
* nothing - do not push anything.
* matching - push all matching branches. All branches having the same name in both ends are considered to be matching. This is the default.
* upstream - push the current branch to its upstream branch.
* tracking - deprecated synonym for upstream.
* current - push the current branch to a branch of the same name.
```

Comment: Was getting incredibly stuck with everything being "up-to-date".

Comment: "git config push.default tracking" This is perfect and updated my repo

Comment: Thanks! It solved my problem! It happened before I defined a default branch to push

Answer (score 13):

**EDIT:** This it seems is not the correct solution, see the comments to the question.  I am leaving the answer because the git add rather than git commit -a hint might help someone in the future.

Hello, did you add before you commited? something like

```
git add .
```

(don't forget the dot)

before the

```
git commit -m "what you changed"
```

(I find this site useful for getting going - http://gitref.org/remotes/#push)

Comment: @wolf The -a only adds a file if the file is already being tracked - give the add command a shot and see if that helps

Comment: The file was already tracked, and `git status -s` properly showed it as modified. After `git commit -a -m "(message)"` it no longer showed up as modified. I tried `git add filename` (because there's some stuff in the directory I don't want to track yet) and push still says 'Everything up-to-date'.

Comment: This was my case. Tried to add git to an existing folder with the exact copy of the repository, thought I shouldn't do `git add .`, was wrong on that one

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
git push upstream yourlocalbranch:master
```

where `yourlocalbranch` could be `master` (which probably would be your local copy of origin master) or any other branch. If unsure use `--verbose` and `--dry-run` options.

Comment: 'git push upstream dev:master' This means it will push source from dev to master. Right? **@bastian**