# How to setup my first git repository and mantain it?

Tags: git, repository, push

I am using git repository for the first time. Following are the things I did

1. I created a folder in my home directory in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS where I will keep all my project files and folders
2. I created an account in github with id and password
3. I created a new repository in the github.
4. Then I used "git push " to sync my folder to git account. It asked for username  and password. I provided that. Then it shows me that everything is upto date.

The problem is that, I cant see my folder and files in github repository

Can anybody help please?

Comment: Did you commit your code to your local repo? (Make sure you make a backup of all your code files if you're not familiar at all with git, to avoid unpleasantnesses if you somehow shoot yourself in the foot.)

Comment: did you `git init` after creating the folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can see a similar example at "[git push says everything up to date when it definitely is not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837290/git-push-says-everything-up-to-date-when-it-definitely-is-not)":

Don't forget to git add and git commit before your first git push.

For that first git push, I would recommend a:

```
git push -u origin master
```

That supposes you have set a remote named 'origin' referring to your github repo:

```
git remote add origin https://UserName@github.com/UserName/repoName
```